# How do I set the consistency level of an individual CQL query in CQL3?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-enterprise, consistency

In the [earlier beta releases of CQ](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/index)L, there was a command I could use to set the read / write consistency of an individual CQL operation. It looked like this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE state='TX' USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM;`

I use CQL3 regularly and have a use-case where I need to be able to perform a read with a higher consistency level than the rest of our application.

I looked through the [CQL3 reference](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html) and didn't find any mention of any CQL syntax that allows me to change the consistency settings on a per-query basis, unless I'm using cqlsh (not useful for application development.)

How am I supposed to tune the consistency on a per-request basis using CQL3?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First set the consistency by running command:

```
CONSISTENCY QUORUM;
```

and then then run you query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE state='TX'
```

At any point you can check the consistency using:

```
 CONSISTENCY;
```

Answer (score 9):

Aaron, the Consistency Level is not needed to be set on the protocol level - for the reasons explained here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4734

Comment: Specifically this means that the driver you are using will tell you how to set it's consistency level.

Answer (score 5):

The default consistency level for any query is "ONE". However, one can set the consistency level on query basis as below.
[image: Setting Consistency Level]

Based on the Replication factor, the location of the partition (nodes list) can be found as below.

nodetool getendpoints Keyspace-name table-name partition-key value

```
$ nodetool getendpoints stresstest status bill
10.134.38.15
10.134.38.24
10.134.38.26
```